# How do i find a matching string, when it contains errors?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-comparison

This is NOT about string1 == string2. Its a little more complicated :-)

I have different people create a lot of PDF-files and report the filenames in a spreadsheet-file.
(This procedure will not be changed for a long time, so please don't suggest so...)

Every week I have to check if all Files in the list are available as PDFs too. 
The Strings have to be IDENTICAL and of course there are always all sorts of errors.
Uppercase vs. lowercase, blank missing, blank at the beginning, character left out, wrong Character inserted...

So currently I'm writing a script that is supposed to find all those strings in both lists that have no match in the other list.
What the strings have in common is, that they contain a date and a number. This number is mostly, but not always unique. 
When the number is used more than once, the rest of the string is different.

So far i can find errors caused by mixing upper- and lowercase. That's easy.
And my script can find matches when the error is caused by leaving out one character.

**My question now is: how can I find the matching string, when more than one Character is wrong and/or the stringlength differs?**

This is what the strings look like:

```
mip - 20140512 - 11     Mip - 20140512 - 11
mip - 20140512 - 27     MiP - 20140512 - 27
mip - 20140512 - 33     mip -20140512 - 33
coty - 20140512 - 35    cotY -20140512 -35
```

Answer (score 0):

well to solve for case and spaces you can compare everything as a lower case and remove all the spaces.

```
var str = "Hello World!";
    var tst = "helloworld!";

var res = str.toLowerCase();
res = res.replace(" ", "");
    if(str == tst)
    {
      // it worked
    }
```

this may not solve for all but should resolve for most of your issues i think.
Should solve for the examples you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to parse the strings in a relaxed way, for example:

```
MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(str, @"^\s*([a-z]+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will allow for leading and trailing spaces, optional spaces around the dashes, and mixed upper and lower case characters.

You can then put the matched parts together in a well formed string:

```
if (m.Count == 1) {
  string wellFormed = m[0].Groups[1].Value.ToLower() + " - " + m[0].Groups[2].Value + " - " + m[0].Groups[3].Value;
  ...
}
```

This would turn for example the string `"cotY -20140512 -35"` into `"coty - 20140512 - 35"`.

If the string doesn't match the pattern, `m.Count` is zero, and you might want to do some secondary checking, or reject it as an invalid string.

You might want to make the pattern more or less relaxed depending on your needs, for example requiring that the date is exact 8 digits to match it (`(\d{8})`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pattern in the sample you listed. If this is always the case you can build a regex that uses the pattern to normalize all the filenames. Once they are all normalized it should be easy to find matches.

```
var coll=[
    ['mip - 20140512 - 11'], 
    ['mip - 20140512 - 27    '],
    ['mip - 20140512 - 33   '] ,
    ['coty - 20140512 - 35  '] ,
    ['Mip - 20140512 - 11'],
    ['  MiP - 20140512 - 27'],
    ['mip -20140512 - 33'],
    ['cotY -20140512 -35']
];


var regx = new RegExp(/([A-Za-z]*)\s*-\s*(\d*)\s*-\s*(\d*)/);
// ([A-Za-z]*)  ... Match1 [$1] group of letters
// \s*          ... followed by zero or more spaces
// -            ... followed by a hypen
// \s*          ... followed by zero or more spaces
// (\d*)        ... Match2 [$2] a group of digits
// \s*          ... followed by zero or more spaces
// -            ... followed by a hyphen
// \s*          ... followed by zero or more spaces
// (\d*)        ... Match3 [$3] a group of digits

function cleanAndPush(el){
    el.push(
        el[0].trim().replace(regx,"$1-$2-$3").toUpperCase()
    );
}

coll.map(cleanAndPush);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fH95m/

Comment: mhm, that sounds clever. Unfortunately THAT pattern is not used by all those who produce the pdf-files. Each one uses his own paatern though.